# Why the cursor fetch null in the procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to do a procedure to fill a table from another table.

But when I call the procedure, this fills with nulls the other table.

The procedure is the following:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE invent()
BEGIN
    DECLARE bDone INT;

    DECLARE hostname VARCHAR(100);

    DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR  
        select hostname from GetInvent;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;
    DROP TABLE Persons;

    CREATE TABLE Persons (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `hostname` VARCHAR(100),
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );

    SET bDone = 0;
    OPEN curs;
    igmLoop: loop
        FETCH curs INTO hostname;

        if bDone = 1 then leave igmLoop; end if;

        INSERT INTO Persons(hostname) VALUES (hostname);

    END LOOP igmLoop;

    CLOSE curs;

    SELECT * FROM Persons;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

In the GetInvent have about 50.000 records the loop work because in the Persons table I get about 50.000 after calling the procedure but with hostname equal to Null.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer to the problem here: [MySQL cursor fetch NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661398/mysql-cursor-fetch-null)

The error was the name of the variable and the name of attribute hostname can´t be same.

The fix procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE invent()
BEGIN
DECLARE bDone INT;

DECLARE v_hostname VARCHAR(100);

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR  
    select hostname from GetInvent;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;
DROP TABLE Persons;

CREATE TABLE Persons (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `hostname` VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

SET bDone = 0;
OPEN curs;
igmLoop: loop
    FETCH curs INTO v_hostname;

    if bDone = 1 then leave igmLoop; end if;

    select v_hostname;

    INSERT INTO Persons(hostname) VALUES (v_hostname);

END LOOP igmLoop;

CLOSE curs;

SELECT * FROM Persons;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```